# What loops are possible when doing this function to the rationals?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

What loops are possible when doing this function to the rationals?

Let's define this function on a simplified fraction $\frac{a}{b}$.

$$f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\frac{a+b}{b+1}$$

I started this with $f(\frac{2}{3})=\frac{5}{4}$ then i did the function again and got this sequence of numbers $\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{4},\frac{9}{5},\frac{7}{3},\frac{5}{2},\frac{7}{3},\dots$ I saw that is starts to loop with $\frac{7}{3},\frac{5}{2}$

Another loop is $\frac{1}{1}$, a one cycle.

Another loop I found was $\frac{2}{1},\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{3}$.

My first question is: from starting from any rational number does it all ways end in a loop or does it ever go to infinity? And my second question is: what sizes of loops are possible?

If the three loops I stated are the only loops prove it

Dark made a post related [What are the possible loops when doing this a type of function to the rationals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3760772/what-are-the-possible-loops-when-doing-this-a-type-of-function-to-the-rationals?noredirect=1#comment7736133_3760772)

Comment: If my program is correct, each of the first $10^7$ positive rationals (in Calkin-Wilf sequence) eventually orbits into one of those three cycles. Among these, the longest lead-in ($44$ steps) was for $14324/23091$, which entered the cycle $(2,3/2,5/3).$

Comment: @JohnHilbert I think this problem has something to do with chaos theory here is a video of a similar problem that might be related   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N92w4e-hrA4 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4LWFzTyhpU

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3760772/what-are-the-possible-loops-when-doing-this-a-type-of-function-to-the-rationals?noredirect=1#comment7736133_3760772

Comment: Computation update: Each of the first $10^{\color{blue}{8}}$ rationals in the Calkin-Wilf sequence eventually orbits into one of those three cycles. Among these, the longest lead-in ($52$ steps) occurs first for $19592/69755,$ which enters the cycle $(2,3/2,5/3).$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a modification of **@Steven Stadnicki**'s proof. The novel contribution of this answer is justifying the reduction step in Steven's solution through the use of a suitable partial order on the set of lattice points.

**Step 1. Settings and Useful Observations**

Let $\mathbb{N}_1 = \{1, 2, 3, \dots\}$ denote the set of positive integers and define $\mathsf{Red} : \mathbb{N}_1^2 \to \mathbb{N}_1^2$ by

$$ \mathsf{Red}(a, b) = \frac{(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}. $$

Also, we equip $\mathbb{N}_1^2$ with the partial order $\leq$ such that<sup>1)</sup>

$$ (a, b) \leq (c, d) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad [b < d]\text{ or }[b = d \text{ and } a \leq c]. $$

The following observations are easy to prove but will be useful throughout.

- $\text{(P1)} \ $ $a \leq c$ and $b \leq d$ implies $(a, b) \leq (c, d)$.
- $\text{(P2)} \ $ $\mathsf{Red}(\mathrm{p}) \leq \mathrm{p}$ for any $\mathrm{p} \in \mathbb{N}_1^2$.

**Step 2. Key Observation**

We will identify each pair $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}_1^2$ satisfying $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ with the simplified fraction $a/b$. Under this identification, we have

$$f(a/b) = \mathsf{Red}(a+b,b+1). $$

Now we will investigate the effect of a suitable number of iterations of $f$. By noting that either $a$ or $b$ must be odd, the following three cases exhaust all the possibilities:

- **Case 1.** Suppose that both $a$ and $b$ are odd. Then both $a+b$ and $b+1$ are even, and so,

  \begin{align*}
  f(a,b)
  = \mathsf{Red}(a+b, b+1)
  = \mathsf{Red}(\tfrac{a+b}{2}, \tfrac{b+1}{2})
  \stackrel{\text{(P2)}}\leq (\tfrac{a+b}{2}, \tfrac{b+1}{2}). \tag{1}
  \end{align*}
- **Case 2.** Suppose that $a$ is odd and $b$ is even. Then by writing $d=\gcd(a+b,b+1)$,

  \begin{align*}
  f^{\circ 2}(a,b)
  = f(\tfrac{a+b}{d},\tfrac{b+1}{d})
  = \mathsf{Red}(\tfrac{a+2b+1}{d},\tfrac{b+d+1}{d}).
  \end{align*}

  Since $d$ is odd, both $a+2b+1$ and $b+d+1$ are even. This means that both are divisible by $2d$, and so,

  \begin{align*}
  f^{\circ 2}(a,b)
  = \mathsf{Red}(\tfrac{a+2b+1}{2d},\tfrac{b+d+1}{2d})
  \stackrel{\text{(P2)}}\leq (\tfrac{a+2b+1}{2d},\tfrac{b+d+1}{2d})
  \stackrel{\text{(P1)}}\leq (\tfrac{a+2b+1}{2},\tfrac{b+2}{2}). \tag{2}
  \end{align*}

  Here, the last inequality follows from the general fact that $\frac{A+Bd}{d}\leq A+B$ for all $A, B \geq 0$ and $d \geq 1$.
- **Case 3.** Suppose that $a$ is even and $b$ is odd. Since $d = \gcd(a+b, b+1)$ is odd, we find that $\frac{a+b}{d}$ is odd and $\frac{b+1}{d}$ is even. So by applying $\text{(2)}$ and using the inequality in the previous step,

  \begin{align*}
  f^{\circ 3}(a,b)
  = f^{\circ 2}(\tfrac{a+b}{d},\tfrac{b+1}{d})
  \stackrel{\text{(2)}}\leq (\tfrac{a+3b+d+2}{2d},\tfrac{b+2d+1}{2d})
  \stackrel{\text{(P1)}}\leq (\tfrac{a+3b+3}{2},\tfrac{b+3}{2}). \tag{3}
  \end{align*}

**Step 3. Proof**

Let $(a, b) \in \mathbb{N}_1$ satisfy $\gcd(a, b) = 1$. Then by $\text{(1)}$–$\text{(3)}$, we observe the following:

1. If $b > 3$, then $\frac{b+3}{2} < b$, and so, a suitable number of iterations by $f$ reduces the second coordinate. This can be repeated finitely many times until the second coordinate becomes $\leq 3$.
2. If $b \leq 3$ and $a > 12$, then $\frac{a+3b+3}{2} < a$, and so, a suitable number of iterations by $f$ reduces the first coordinate. Similarly as before, this can be repeated finitely many times until the first coordinate becomes $\leq 12$.
3. If $a \leq 12$ and $b \leq 3$, then a suitable number of iterations by $f$ will map $(a, b)$ into another point $(a', b')$ with $a' \leq 12$ and $b' \leq 3$. So by the pigeonhole principle, iteration by $f$ will eventually fall into a cycle.
4. By checking all the possible $12+6+8=26$ cases manually, we find that there are only three types of cycles:
   $$ (1, 1) \qquad (5, 2), (7, 4) \qquad (2, 1), (3, 2), (5, 3) $$

This completes the proof.

---

<sup>1) Note that this is exactly the [colexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Colexicographic_order) induced by the usual order on $\mathbb{N}_1$.</sup>

Answer (score 10):

The key here is that for parity reasons, we'll always get to a 'smaller' fraction in a short, finite number of stages. Rather than fractions, I'll refer to an iteration on a pair of numbers $f:\langle a,b\rangle \mapsto \mathop{Red}(\langle a+b,b+1\rangle)$ where $\mathop{Red}()$ denotes reduction $\mathop{Red}(\langle a,b\rangle) = \langle\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)},\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\rangle $. We'll start by inducting on the value of $b$, to show that we need to only consider a small number of values of $b$ when looking for cycles. Note that $a$ and $b$ can't both be even, so there are three cases: $a=2m+1, b=2n$, $a=2m, b=2n+1$, and $a=2m+1, b=2n+1$. The third case immediately goes to $\langle a',b'\rangle$ $=\mathop{Red}(\langle 2m+2n+2,2n+2\rangle)$ $=\mathop{Red}(\langle m+n+1,n+1\rangle)$; this might reduce even further, but this is good enough for our purposes. note that $b'=n+1\lt b=2n+1$, so the value of $b$ always reduces in this case unless $b=1$.

In the case $a=2m+1, b=2n$, the map goes $\langle 2m+1, 2n\rangle$ $\mapsto \mathop{Red}(\langle 2m+2n+1, 2n+1\rangle)$ $\mapsto\mathop{Red}(\langle 2m+4n+2, 2n+2\rangle)$ $=\mathop{Red}(\langle m+2n+1, n+1\rangle)$. Here we have $b'=n+1\lt b=2n$ as long as $b\gt 2$.

Finally, in the case $a=2m, b=2n+1$, the map goes $\langle 2m, 2n+1\rangle \mapsto\mathop{Red}(\langle 2m+2n+1, 2n+2\rangle)$ $\mapsto\mathop{Red}(\langle 2m+4n+3, 2n+3\rangle)$ $\mapsto\mathop{Red}(\langle 2m+6n+6, 2n+4\rangle) = \mathop{Red}(\langle m+3n+3, n+2\rangle)$. Here, $b'=n+2\lt b=2n+1$ as long as $b\gt 3$.

Together, these mean that we can study the effects of the iteration specifically on the cases $\langle a,b\rangle: b\in \{1,2,3\}$; any larger $b$ will eventually reduce to a $b$ in this range. More specifically, we have the cases $\langle a, 1\rangle$, $\langle 2m+1, 2\rangle$, and $\langle 2m, 3\rangle$ to study. I'm going to use a different form of induction on these cases, based on the value of $a+b$.

Let's start with the case $\langle a,1\rangle$. If $a$ is odd, then we have $\langle 2m+1, 1\rangle \mapsto \langle m+1, 1\rangle$; here $a'+b'=m+2$ will always be less than $a+b=2m+2$. If $a$ is even, then we have the case $\langle 2m, 1\rangle$; by the logic above, this maps to $\mathop{Red}(\langle m+3, 3\rangle)$. We get a smaller value for the sum as long as $a+b=2m+1\gt a'+b'=m+6$, or in other words as long as $m\gt 5$ (i.e., $a\gt 10$).

Next up, we have the case $\langle 2m+1, 2\rangle$; by the logic above, this maps to $\mathop{Red}(\langle m+3, 2\rangle)$. Since $a'+b'=m+5\lt a+b=2m+3$ as long as $m\gt 2$, we can see that any pair $\langle a,2\rangle$ with $a$ an odd number greater than $5$ will yield  new pair with a smaller sum.

Finally, we have the case $\langle 2m, 3\rangle$; once again, using the logic above we see that this will map to $\mathop{Red}(\langle m+6, 3\rangle)$. Here we have $a+b=2m+3\gt a'+b'=m+9$ as long as $m\gt 6$, or in other words $a\gt 12$.

Putting this all together, we can see that cases of the form $\langle a,b\rangle$ with $b\leq 3$ always yield another case of similar form with smaller $a$ as long as $a\gt 12$; this leaves only a finite number of values to check, which yields the loops that have already been found.

Comment: Writing $g(\langle a,b\rangle)=\langle a+b,b+1\rangle$ so that $f=\mathit{Red}\circ g$, you seem to be claiming that $$(f\circ f\circ f)(\langle a, b \rangle)=(\mathit{Red}\circ g\circ g \circ g)(\langle a,b\rangle),$$ especially in the case $a=2m$ and $b=2n+1$. However, $$\langle 6,7\rangle\stackrel{f}\mapsto\langle13,8\rangle\stackrel{f}\mapsto\langle7,3\rangle\stackrel{f}\mapsto\langle5,2\rangle$$ whereas $$\langle 6,7\rangle\stackrel{g}\mapsto\langle13,8\rangle\stackrel{g}\mapsto\langle21,9\rangle\stackrel{g}\mapsto\langle30,10\rangle\stackrel{\mathit{Red}}\mapsto\langle3,1\rangle.$$

Comment: How do you justify $\mathop{Red}(\langle 2m+2n+1, 2n+1\rangle) \mapsto\mathop{Red}(\langle 2m+4n+2, 2n+2\rangle)$? For example for $m=5$,$n=2$, the first fraction is $15/5=3/1$, which should be mapped to $4/2=2$. But the second fraction you map it to is $20/6\neq 2$. Am I missing something? I guess my point is contained in SangchulLee's comment.

Comment: @Sil, I believe so. Indeed, the non-homogeneous nature of the map $(a,b)\mapsto(a+b,b+1)$ makes the problem hard and interesting, but this answer seems not taking that point into consideration. Indeed, in the case $a=2m+1$ and $b=2n$, we also have a counter-example: $$\langle7,8\rangle\stackrel{f}\mapsto\langle5,3\rangle\stackrel{f}\mapsto\langle2,1\rangle,$$ whereas $$\langle7,8\rangle\stackrel{g}\mapsto\langle15,9\rangle\stackrel{g}\mapsto\langle24,10\rangle\stackrel{\mathit{Res}}\mapsto\langle12,5\rangle.$$

Comment: As a possible correction, I guess that we might equip $\mathbb{N}_1^2$ with a suitable partial ordering $\leq$ satisfying (1) $\mathit{Rad}(\mathrm{p})\leq\mathrm{p}$ for all $\mathrm{p}\in\mathbb{N}_1^2$ and (2) $\mathrm{p}\leq\mathrm{q}$ implies $g(\mathrm{p})\leq g(\mathrm{q})$ for all $\mathrm{p},\mathrm{q} \in \mathbb{N}_1^2$, where $g$ is the map $\langle a,b\rangle\mapsto\langle a+b,b+1\rangle$.

Comment: @SangchulLee, Sil: I'll try to edit my answer for more precision; the core induction argument (after at most four steps we'll get a smaller value of $b$ as long as $b\gt 3$) still holds since $\mathop{Red}()$ will be dividing $b$ by at least 3 in those cases where my current argument is inaccurate.

Comment: I succeed in justifying the reduction step and posted as a separate answer. Of course, most part of my answer is based on your solution, so the credit definitely goes to you. (+1)